# Is RTS & CTS important in UART communcation

Tags: uart

I am starting with UART communication in `PIC32MX795F512l`. This UART will communicate with PC. I was just wondering that it is important to connect `RTS` & `CTS` or just connecting Rx Tx GND will make the communication? Some websites say RTS & CTS are also important but some say that its not important. I am really confused. Please help.!

Comment: They're only important if the device uses them.

Comment: I didnt get you properly.?

Comment: RTS and CTS are hardware handshaking signals. As such, they're usually optional, as most transmitters and receivers can be configured to either use these signals or not. Only connecting VCC, GND, Rx and Tx will work. Don't forget to cross the pairs so PC Rx goes to PIC Tx and PC Tx goes to PIC Rx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTS & CTS are not always important. You can directly make cross connections like

Rx -> Tx

Tx -> Rx

GND -> GND

Answer (score 0):

Rx, Tx, GND pins are enough for communication. However in UART bootloader applications RTS pin is important and used for resetting MCU